# How to turn on or off bluetooth in android using python

Tags: android, python

I want to turn on or off the visibility of bluetooth in android using python code. Can you help me ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, it would be a pretty big security hole to let apps change settings.

Comment: Do you mean python or monkeyrunner, from the device itself or from the development computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using SL4A with python so lets go.

```
import android #import android module
droid = android.Android() #class instantation
droid.bluethoothMakeDiscoverable() #make your device visible
```

It is easy, anyway you may want to check the sl4a bluethooth fecade, there are all the bluetooth commands you may need.